# BoxEdit does not "recognizing" my exe as a specific filetype editor

Tags: box-api

Concerns the **BoxEdit** App.

I have created a custom reader/editor for opening/editing files of a certain type (for sack of example ".msbsod").

1) When my editor is set to be the default program to open ".msbsod" files, the edit button is disabled and Box shows me this error:

> This file type cannot be edited

2) If I set the ".msbsod" file type default program to be notepad. BoxEdit works as expected.

**QUESTIONS:**
1) What is BoxEdit looking for on my system, to say that a certain application can or can't edit/open a document of a specific file type.
2) Is there a way to open files of type ".msbsod" to be editable all the time.

I don't doubt my custom editor is the problem (I'm 99% sure it is the whole problem), I just want to know what registry entry I need to make to get this to work!

***NOTE:***
If I set notepad as the default, load the browser preview page (edit is enabled), switch the default to my editor. It works as expected, but if I navigate away from that preview page all future ".msbsod" files I encounter have the "edit" button disabled again.

Happy Prep for BoxWorks!!1

Thanks so much for Any/All Help.
-Alex

Answer (score 0):

Box Edit relies on a Windows API to determine which application to use when clicking Edit.  Unfortunately, it turns out that this API is not always reliable.  The good news is that we've figured out how to work around the gaps, and we have a solution that should solve this use case.  It's slated to go out within the next few weeks.

Hope that helps.